# How to display multiple columns in a UITableView using Xamarin IOS?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

i am trying to display multiple table cells in table View using Xamarin IOS, But it always gives one cell in table row instead of two cells.
Please refer below images for more understand.

[image]

please find code below.

```
//Table Cell Code

public class GridItemCell : UITableViewCell
{
    public static readonly string ID = "MultiColumnCell";
    NSString cellIdentifier;
    bool status;

    public UILabel LeftValue { get; set; }
    public UILabel RightValue { get; set; }

    public GridItemCell()
    {
        LeftValue = new UILabel(new RectangleF(0, 5, 15, 50));
        RightValue = new UILabel(new RectangleF(15, 5, 15, 50));
        LeftValue.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
        RightValue.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;

        AddSubview(LeftValue);
        AddSubview(RightValue);
    }
}  

//Table Source
public class GridItemSource : UITableViewSource
{
    public virtual nint NumberOfRowsInSections(UITableView tableView)
    {
        return 2;
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        return 5;
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(GridItemCell.ID) as GridItemCell;
        if(cell == null)
        {
            cell = new GridItemCell();
        }
        cell.LeftValue.Text = "Left " + indexPath.Row;
        cell.RightValue.Text = "Right " + indexPath.Row;
        return cell;
    }
}  

//View Controller Code

UITableView _tableView = new UITableView
        {
            Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 60, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height - 26),
            Source = new ProductItemsSource(data,strCategoryViewType,this),
            AlwaysBounceVertical = false
        };
```

By using this code, i am getting table view with one cell. But i need two different cells in one row with cell selection. 
Can any one help me to fix this issue.

Comment: I think that UICollectionView would be more suited for this. A UITableView shows one cell per row, you could make a Cell with two items in it to achieve what you're trying.

Comment: Thank you @Pilatus

Answer (score 3):

You will want to use a `UICollectionView` instead of a `UITableView` to achieve what you are looking for.

Table views are normally based upon a single data set per row, you could return a collection of two sets of image/item/price and your cell would actually be displaying both sets of data at the same time, but this is really breaking how table views were designed to be used (auto-caching, iOS UI styling, etc..)

#### Per Apple:

> **Collection views provide the same general function as table views except that a collection view is able to support more than just single-column layouts**.

Ref: [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/index.html)

Xamarin has a great tech article on using collection views:

[image]
[Introduction to Collection Views](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/introduction_to_collection_views/)

Comment: Thank you @SushiHangover. I will use UICollectionView to complete my task.

Comment: @IntellectWizard no problem, once you switch over to `UICollectionView` if you have any problems, post a new question, till then, cheers